# gChartPHP documentation

Tags: php, char

I want to use PHP wrapper of Google chart API - [gChartPHP](https://github.com/pacbard/gChartPhp). However, no matter how much time I searched for documentation I couldn't find it. There are a number of important topics in there. Where is it hidden?

Comment: You prpbably will have a hard time finding docs for it. Your best best would be to download the zip package, and follow according to the example provided in it.

Comment: Hi redskins80, I did that yes - but I would need to find some params for transpraency which are obviously only in the documentation (stated in the link above). I guess I will try something different as these image charts are deprecated. Regards

Comment: Maybe the author meant the documentation of the google chart API over @ google? The lib merely is a wrapper, so I guess you still need to know the google documentation. Otherwise, do what @cweiske suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and run [phpdocumentor2](http://phpdoc.org/) on it. It will give you a nice overview on all classes as well as all methods you can use.

Alternatively, read the source.

Comment: Thanks, it's not what I expected but at least now I know how to use it.